# I can't see my app published with github pages

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

I made a simple app with ReactJS, I put it on GitHub server using GitHub Pages but it doesn't show and I have no error in the browser console !

Here is the link : https://meriemu.github.io/reactjsBlog/

And the package.json

```
{
  "homepage": "https://Meriemu.github.io/reactjsBlog",
  "name": "react-blog-smooth-scroll",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "animejs": "^3.2.1",
    "firebase": "^9.13.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.6.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-scroll": "^1.8.8",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.6",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
..
...
....
```

Comment: How do you init the app? Can you show some code? Otherwise we know as much as you do.

Comment: thank you @CornelRaiu for your response, which part of code do you want to see ? i used create-react-app for the first time. i updated my post